# How to get query string from an url in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I would like to know how to get a query string from an url using coldfusion.

I have following url: 
http://mypage.com/books/8540/index.cfm?current_book=215487 
Now I would like to extract current_book=215487 in a var. The code below returns only the current URL.

```
<cfset currentURL = cgi.request_url/>
```

Comment: There is an existing variable in the cgi scope.  Either look at your debugging information or dump the entire scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a scope that URL variables are stored called the `URL` scope (there is also one for FORM variables called `FORM`).

If you want to get it, you should make sure it is set, which you can do with a `<cfparam>` call:

```
<cfparam name="url.current_book" default="">
<cfset current_book = url.current_book>
```

Now you can use the `current_book` variable if you need to, or access the `url.current_book` variable directly like:

```
<cfoutput>
You chose #HTMLEditFormat(url.current_book)#
</cfoutput>
```

Which would output `You chose 215487`

Comment: Note that you must *never* output user-supplied data of any kind into the page without escaping it properly. This would be an open door for XSS attacks. `HTMLEditFormat()` (or its modern cousin `encodeForHTML()`) are required for output into HTML, `XMLFormat()` (or `encodeForXml`) for output to XML, `encodeForJavaScript()` for JS, etc.